# please help me in how to assign a list of string fetched from apex class to a lightning radio group options in html lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

Please help me in assigning the list of strings fetched from apex class as options in lightning radio options in LWC

```apex
public static List<String> getPicklistValues(){ 
    List<String> pickListValues = new List<String>(); 
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult pickList = Task3__mdt.case_template_type__c.getDescribe(); 
    for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickVal : pickList.getPicklistValues()){ 
        pickListValues.add(pickVal.getValue()); 
    } 
    System.debug('value: '+pickListValues); 
    return pickListValues; 
}
```

```html
<lightning-radio-group 
    name="AradioGroup" 
    label="Please select a Template type" 
    options={options} 
    value={value} 
    type="radio">
</lightning-radio-group>
```

Comment: please share some of the code you have already written that way would be easier to help you.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide details. See [ask] and [help/on-topic] for more guidance on the SFSE format and expectations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Review the documentation [lightning-radiogroup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-radio-group/documentation):

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class MyComponentName extends LightningElement {
    options = [
        { label: 'Ross', value: 'option1' },
        { label: 'Rachel', value: 'option2' },
    ];

    // Select option1 by default
    value = 'option1';

    handleChange(event) {
        const selectedOption = event.detail.value;
        console.log('Option selected with value: ' + selectedOption);
    }
}
```

*.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-radio-group
        label="Radio Button Group"
        options={options}
        value={value}
        onchange={handleChange}
        required
    >
    </lightning-radio-group>
</template>
```

As you can see the **options** attribute requires a list of key-values.
You have two options:

1. Create key-values in the .cls
2. Create key-values in the .js file

I personally prefer doing it in .js

```
getData(){
   return getPicklistValues({})
      .then(result => {
        // typo here, not "this.options =>" , "this.options = " 
        this.options = result.map(picklistValue => {
          return { label: picklistValue, value: picklistValue}
        });
      }).catch(error => {
        //handle error
      })

}
```

Comment: this.options => result.map(picklistValue=> {

Comment: getting error like missing semicolon